# Execute a command before hibernation ubuntu on lid close

Tags: 20.04, scripts, google-chrome, hibernate, process

I am wondering if there is a way to execute a script (for example I want the script to close all brave and node process), but I have already configured Ubuntu to hibernate on lid close, is there a way to make that script or to kill the proccesses before hibernation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a service, say `/etc/systemd/system/ibraham-pre-hibernate.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ibrahim before hibernation service
Before=systemd-hibernate.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ibrahim/services/script-to-close-processes.sh

[Install]
RequiredBy=hibernate.target
```

Modify the above for the location of your script.

Once everything is setup, enable the service (the example is for a different service, one of mine, so you can see the expected reply (well, your target is different)):

```
doug@s19:~$ sudo systemctl enable doug-post-boot-s19.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/doug-post-boot-s19.service → /etc/systemd/system/doug-post-boot-s19.service.
```